# How can I save user account verification code to a text file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, sms, text-files

I want to be able to activate the user account using mobile number, the account activation code should be saved in a text file. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: please let use know what you have tried  so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Storage

```
use Storage;

Storage::put('file.txt', $activationCode);
```

Take a look at this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: Thank you Rik Peeters, May you explains a bit further. Should I generate the random code in my RegistrationController?

Comment: You should put the code where you handle your logic. If that's what you mean.